# How do I delete a top level QTreeWidgetItem from a QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm attempting to remove a top level tree widget item if there are no child nodes within the top level item. What is the correct way to do this? I can't seem to find the API call within Qt's documentation. Is it safe to just call delete on the top level tree widget item? I haven't run into any issues yet, but I'd like to know if that's safe practice. Thanks much.

```
if(topLevelTreeWidgetItem->childCount() > 1) {
  topLevelTreeWidgetItem->removeChild(childItem);
}
else
{
  delete topLevelTreeWidgetItem;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`delete`ing a QTreeWidgetItem directly is perfectly safe.

According to the documentation for [~QTreeWidgetItem()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#dtor.QTreeWidgetItem):

> Destroys this tree widget item. The item will be removed from
>   QTreeWidgets to which it has been added. This makes it safe to delete
>   an item at any time.

I've used `delete` on many QTreeWidgetItems in practice and it works quite well.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. I have made my top level items in my QTreeWidget QTreeWidgetItem pointers in order to make reference to them throughout my code. Making them pointers makes it easy to delete them and re-initialize them if needed.

Answer (score 5):

To delete a top level item call [QTreeWidget::takeTopLevelItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#takeTopLevelItem) method and then delete the returned item:

```
delete treeWidget->takeTopLevelItem(index);
```

Where index is index of the item to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Function takeChild only works with QTreeWidgetItem. With QtreeWidget, you can use [QtreeWidget::takeTopLevelItem(int index)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#takeTopLevelItem)